# How to migrate old properties into a new object with Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm, realm-migration

Previously, I had only one object that had every value that I needed. I "regrouped" them and made separate objects. I added properties with the type of the new objects to the original object.
How can I assign the old property values to the object's properties?

Here's the code for my objects:

```
class MainObject: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    // Schema 0
    dynamic var otherId: Int = 0
    dynamic var otherStr: String = ""

    dynamic var anotherId: Int = 0
    dynamic var anotherD: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var anotherText: String = ""

    // Schema 1
    dynamic var otherObjectVar: OtherObject?
    dynamic var anotherObjectVar: AnotherObject?
}

// Schema 1
class OtherObject: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var str: String = 0
}
class AnotherObject: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var d: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var text: String = ""
}
```

*(Changed variable names)*

I tried to use `convenience init(){}` but it didn't work. I also tried to assign an object instance to the newObject, but that didn't work either.
Here's that code for easier understanding:

```
let other = OtherObject()
other.id = 0
other.str = oldObject["otherStr"] as! string
newObject["otherObjectVar"] = other
```

How can I migrate the old properties into a new property which is another object?

EDIT: Temporarily, I solved it with

```
let obj = migration.create(MainObject.className())
migration.delete(obj)
```

but I don't think this is the right solution. So if anyone has a solution for this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're doing this during schema migration, you need to use `migration.create` to create new objects, not their init. Then you would set them on the new object, along the lines of:

```
let other = migration.create(OtherObject.className())
other["id"] = 0
other["str"] = oldObject["otherStr"] as! String
newObject?["otherObjectVar"] = other
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it the schema migration. I tried your answer, but I get this error: `Value of type 'MigrationObject' (aka 'DynamicObject') has no member 'id'`The object has an id field, so it shouldn't show an error.

Comment: This should actually be `other["id"]` and `other["str"]`. The reason you're getting that error message @Daniel is that Realm objects in a migration block aren't your typed models (that obviously wouldn't work when dealing with objects from older schema versions, whose typed models are no longer around).

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect this. It should be correct now.